# Orbital quadrature and relative velocities

Tags: orbital-motion, doppler-effect

In Robert J. Sawyer's sf novel *The Oppenheimer Alternative*, a bunch of physicists try to find the composition of the martian atmosphere with spectroscopy. They say that to find water vapour or oxygen, a good technique is to use orbital quadrature, i.e., when the line from the Sun to the Earth and the line from Mars to Earth cross at 90 degrees. At that point, Mars relative velocity with respecto to Earth will be a maximum, so the Doppler shift will allow to see the water vapour or oxygen truly from Mars, not those from Earth.

I didn't know of this technique, but I have been thinking about the fact that the relative velocity of Mars with respect to Earth will be a maximum in quadrature, but I can't find this to be necessarily true. Do you know/have a proof of it? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that Earth ($E$) and Mars ($M$) orbit the Sun ($S$) on circular orbits in the same plane, with radii $r_E$ and $r_M$, respectively. Call $\alpha$ the angle $\widehat{SEM}$ and $\beta$ the angle $\widehat{SME}$. The law of sines in the triangle $\Delta SEM$ gives us the relation
$$
r_E\sin\alpha = r_M\sin\beta.
$$
The velocity of the Earth is perpendicular to the line $SE$, so the velocity of Earth along the line $EM$ is given by
$$
\bar{v}_E = v_E\cos(\pi/2-\alpha) = v_E\sin\alpha.
$$
Likewise, the velocity of Mars along the line $EM$ is
$$
\bar{v}_M = v_M\cos(\pi/2-\beta) = v_M\sin\beta.
$$
Therefore, the relative velocity between Earth and Mars along the line $EM$ is
$$
\bar{v} = \bar{v}_E - \bar{v}_M = \left(v_E - \frac{r_E}{r_M}v_M\right)\sin\alpha,
$$
which is maximal if $\alpha= \pi/2$.